# Clojure: How do I apply a function to a subset of the entries in a hash-map?

Tags: dictionary, clojure, hashmap

I am not to Clojure and attempting to figure out how to do this.

I want to create a new hash-map that for a subset of the keys in the hash-map applies a function to the elements. What is the best way to do this?

```
(let 
   [my-map {:hello "World" :try "This" :foo "bar"}]
   (println (doToMap my-map [:hello :foo] (fn [k] (.toUpperCase k)))
```

This should then result a map with something like

```
{:hello "WORLD" :try "This" :foo "BAR"}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
(defn do-to-map [amap keyseq f]
  (reduce #(assoc %1 %2 (f (%1 %2))) amap keyseq))
```

## Breakdown:

It helps to look at it inside-out.  In Clojure, hash-maps act like functions; if you call them like a function with a key as an argument, the value associated with that key is returned.  So given a single key, the current value for that key can be obtained via:

```
(some-map some-key)
```

We want to take old values, and change them to new values by calling some function `f` on them.  So given a single key, the new value will be:

```
(f (some-map some-key))
```

We want to associate this new value with this key in our hash-map, "replacing" the old value.  This is what `assoc` does:

```
(assoc some-map some-key (f (some-map some-key)))
```

("Replace" is in scare-quotes because we're not mutating a single hash-map object; we're returning new, immutable, altered hash-map objects each time we call `assoc`.  This is still fast and efficient in Clojure because hash-maps are persistent and share structure when you `assoc` them.)

We need to repeatedly `assoc` new values onto our map, one key at a time.  So we need some kind of looping construct.  What we want is to start with our original hash-map and a single key, and then "update" the value for that key.  Then we take that new hash-map and the next key, and "update" the value for that next key.  And we repeat this for every key, one at a time, and finally return the hash-map we've "accumulated".  This is what `reduce` does.

- The first argument to `reduce` is a function that takes two arguments: an "accumulator" value, which is the value we keep "updating" over and over; and a single argument used in one iteration to do some of the accumulating.
- The second argument to `reduce` is the initial value passed as the first argument to this `fn`.
- The third argument to `reduce` is a collection of arguments to be passed as the second argument to this `fn`, one at a time.

So:

```
(reduce fn-to-update-values-in-our-map 
        initial-value-of-our-map 
        collection-of-keys)
```

`fn-to-update-values-in-our-map` is just the `assoc` statement from above, wrapped in an anonymous function:

```
(fn [map-so-far some-key] (assoc map-so-far some-key (f (map-so-far some-key))))
```

So plugging it into `reduce`:

```
(reduce (fn [map-so-far some-key] (assoc map-so-far some-key (f (map-so-far some-key))))
        amap
        keyseq)
```

In Clojure, there's a shorthand for writing anonymous functions: `#(...)` is an anonymous `fn` consisting of a single form, in which `%1` is bound to the first argument to the anonymous function, `%2` to the second, etc.  So our `fn` from above can be written equivalently as:

```
#(assoc %1 %2 (f (%1 %2)))
```

This gives us:

```
(reduce #(assoc %1 %2 (f (%1 %2))) amap keyseq)
```

Comment: Would you mind giving a statement by statement description for us new to Clojure?

Comment: That #(...) notation is awesome. Great answer!

Comment: Fantastic answer.  Appreciate you walking it through step by step!

Answer (score 4):

```
(defn doto-map [m ks f & args]
  (reduce #(apply update-in %1 [%2] f args) m ks))
```

Example call

```
user=> (doto-map {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} [:a :c] + 2)
{:a 3, :b 2, :c 5}
```

Hopes this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work:

```
(defn doto-map [ks f amap]
  (into amap
    (map (fn [[k v]] [k (f v)])
         (filter (fn [[k v]] (ks k)) amap))))

user=> (doto-map #{:hello :foo} (fn [k] (.toUpperCase k)) {:hello "World" :try "This" :foo "bar"})
{:hello "WORLD", :try "This", :foo "BAR"}
```

There might be a better way to do this. Perhaps someone can come up with a nice one-liner :)