# Idiomatic way to convert some hash-map values to floats in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I've got a simple `to-float` function:

```
(defn to-float [v] (cond
                     (nil? v) nil
                     (string? v) (Float/parseFloat v)
                     :else (float v)))
```

And a record:

```
(defrecord Product [Id UseRecommendation ReferenceProductId OnePrice TotalPrice
                    ManualTotalPrice MarketTotalPrice PreviousTotalPrice PurchaseTotalPrice
                    Tax Deposit RuleId RoleId PrimaryProduct Size])
```

For some of the keys(?) I wish to make sure they are float before passing them to `map->Product` (constructor?). Sorry I'm not familiar with the terminology here.

Anyway, my first solution was very verbose:

```
(defn init->Product [args]
  (let [converted-args (assoc args
                         :TotalPrice         (to-float (:TotalPrice args))
                         :ManualTotalPrice   (to-float (:ManualTotalPrice args))
                         :MarketTotalPrice   (to-float (:MarketTotalPrice args))
                         :PreviousTotalPrice (to-float (:PreviousTotalPrice args))
                         :PurchaseTotalPrice (to-float (:PurchaseTotalPrice args))
                         :Tax                (to-float (:Tax args))
                         :Deposit            (to-float (:Deposit args)))]
    (map->Product converted-args)))
```

Second one was better but has lots of "noise" in terms of `apply`, `merge`, `hash-map` and so forth:

```
(defn init->Product [args]
  (let [apply-float (fn [keys] (merge args (apply merge (map #(hash-map % (to-float (% args))) keys))))]
    (map->Product (apply-float '(:TotalPrice :ManualTotalPrice :MarketTotalPrice :PreviousTotalPrice :PurchaseTotalPrice :Tax :Deposit)))))
```

The third solution uses recursion, which isn't easy to comprehend for people who are new to Clojure either:

```
(defn init->Product [args-orig]
  (let [apply-float (fn [args keys] (if (empty? keys) args (let [key (first keys)] (recur (assoc args key (to-float (key args))) (rest keys)))))]
    (map->Product (apply-float args-orig '(:TotalPrice :ManualTotalPrice :MarketTotalPrice :PreviousTotalPrice :PurchaseTotalPrice :Tax :Deposit)))))
```

Can you think of something simpler? I have a feeling there exists an utility function I'm missing here, or I fail to see how `reduce` or some other could be used.

Edit: This is more like how I would do it in Python

```
(defn init->Product [args-orig]
  (let [apply-float (fn [args keys] (merge args (into {} (map (fn [key] [key (to-float (key args))]) keys))))]
    (map->Product (apply-float args-orig '(:TotalPrice :ManualTotalPrice :MarketTotalPrice :PreviousTotalPrice :PurchaseTotalPrice :Tax :Deposit)))))
```

Comment: Similar question and answers at http://stackoverflow.com/q/1638854.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `(assoc m :x (f (:x m)))` you may use `(update m :x f)`. So, I would rewrite your `init->Product` function as follows:

```
(defn init->Product [args]
  (let [converted-args (reduce #(update %1 %2 to-float)
                               args
                               [:TotalPrice
                                :ManualTotalPrice
                                :MarketTotalPrice
                                :PreviousTotalPrice
                                :PurchaseTotalPrice
                                :Tax
                                :Deposit])]
    (map->Product converted-args)))
```

Comment: Shouldn't `convert-args` actually be `converted-args`? Also, can't you just use `(keys args)` instead of `[:TotalPrice :ManualTotalPrice :MarketTotalPrice :PreviousTotalPrice :PurchaseTotalPrice :Tax :Deposit]`?

Comment: I assumed that `to-float` should be called only on some subset of  `(keys args)`. Look at the definition of `Product` record: there are fields that are not converted to float.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Carry on, then. :)

Comment: Great, thanks! That is more like what I had in mind, `update` made this simple to implement.